# XDocument.Parse: Avoid replacing XXE references

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml, xxe

I'm trying to protect against malicious XXE injections in the XMLs processed by my app. Therefore I'm using XDocument instead of XmlDocument.

The XML represents the payload of a web request so I call XDocument.Parse on its string content. However, I'm seeing the XXE references contained in the XML (&XXE) being replaced in the result with the actual value of ENTITY xxe.

Is it possible to parse the XML with XDocument without replacing &xxe ?

Thanks

EDIT:
I managed to avoid the replacement of xxes in the XML using `XmlResolver=null` for `XDocument.Load`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `Parse` try to use `Load` with a pre-configured reader:

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(new XmlTextReader(
    new StringReader(xmlContent)) { EntityHandling = EntityHandling.ExpandCharEntities });
```

From MSDN:

> When EntityHandling is set to ExpandCharEntities, the reader expands character entities and returns general entities as EntityReference nodes.

Comment: I don't want to expand the entities, that would mean I'm injected.

Comment: This will expand only the character entities, such as `&#65;` but preserves any other entities, like `&XEE;`. At least, the `XmlReader` will return `XmlNodeType.EntityReference` instead of text. See the Remarks here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextreader.entityhandling%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Use the following example to stop resolving XXE (schemas and DTD).

```
Dim objXmlReader As System.Xml.XmlTextReader = Nothing
objXmlReader = New System.Xml.XmlTextReader(_patternFilePath)
objXmlReader.XmlResolver = Nothing
patternDocument = XDocument.Load(objXmlReader)
```