# XElement.Parse and special characters in attribute

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have a string containing xml e.g.:

```
<Person Name="Molly O&apos;Mahony" />
```

I want to convert this to an XElement, maintaining the `& apos ;` and not converting it to '

using

```
XElement.Parse(string);
```

creates the element `<Person Name="Molly O'Mahony" />`
Is this possible?

Comment: What makes you think it will be converted? What code do you have now?

Comment: using XElement.Parse(string) converts it

Comment: @dbc OP means value in attribute. His sample is not valid xml anyway, but he means something like `<Name Attr="Molly O&apos;Mahony" />`

Comment: Sorry, I fixed the (bad) example I had posted above.

Comment: Why do you care about the encoding anyway? It's the same thing in XML.

Comment: @DavidG because there will be a CRC check at some point

Comment: Then you can't parse it into an `XElement` unless you manually replace all apostrophes with the encoded value when you export back to string.

Comment: Entity expansion is done at the low level by `XmlReader`.  As shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33255946/3744182) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42765970/3744182) if you switch to `XmlTextReader` you can disable expansion of *general* entities by setting `EntityHandling = EntityHandling.ExpandCharEntities` but there isn't a way to disable expansion of character entities.  The suggestion is to create your own subclass of `XmlReader`.  (And of course you would need to subclass `XmlWriter` to avoid escaping then when serializing.)

Comment: But `&apos` is a [predefined XML entity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Predefined_entities_in_XML).  *Every* XML reader in *every* framework is going to convert it to an apostrophe because the XML spec *requires that all XML processors honor them.*  Are you really sure this will cause problems down the road?

Comment: If you are going to have CRC check, I suppose it will be on whole xml document, not on separate attributes?

Answer (score 0):

Here we go:

```
var txt = "<Person Name=\"Molly O&apos;Mahony\" />";

var e  = XElement.Parse(txt, LoadOptions.SetLineInfo);
var li = (IXmlLineInfo) e.Attribute("Name");

// li.LinePosition points to first char of the attribute: Name="Molly O&apos;Mahony"
//                                                        ^

var start = txt.IndexOf('"', li.LinePosition) + 1;  
var end   = txt.IndexOf('"', start);
var len   = end - start;

var attr  = txt.Substring(start, len); // Molly O&apos;Mahony
```

You might need to adjust the code to make it work with multi-line text.